# How can I view structure and foreign keys of a classic HyperFileSQL database?

Tags: sql, database, db-structure, hyperfilesql

I have a classic HyperfileSQL database which I need to convert (.FIC files)

I'm trying to get some overview of the structures and keys in the database. So I downloaded WinDev Express, and I got the 'HyperFileSQL Control Center' now.

With this tool, I can open the files, and i can see that there are keys on some columns. But I can't find a way to see details of the key (key to what table?).

How can I get more details on this, to get a good view of the total database structure?

Thanks for any advice on this..

Answer (score 0):

The relationships are set at Analysis Level (.WDA).
The analysis is then responsible to generate .FIC and .NDX (indices) files.